# Docker ping container on other nodes

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I have 2 virtual machines (VM1 with IP 192.168.56.101 and VM2 with IP 192.16.56.102 which can ping each other) and these are the steps I'm doing:

```
- Create consul container on VM1 with 'docker run -d -p 8500:8500 --name=consul progrium/consul -server -bootstrap'
- Create swarm manager on VM1 with 'docker run -d -p 3376:3376 swarm manage -H 0.0.0.0:3376 --advertise 192.168.56.101:3376 consul://192.168.56.101:8500
- Create swarm agents on each VM with 'docker run -d swarm join --advertise <VM-IP>:2376 consul://192.168.56.101:8500
```

If i run docker -H 0.0.0.0:3376 info I can see both nodes connected to the swarm and they are both healthy. I can also run container and they are scheduled to the nodes. However, If I create a network and assign a few nodes to this network and then SSH into one node and try to ping every other node I can only reach the nodes which are running on the same virtual machine.

Both Virtual Machines have these DOCKER_OPTS:

```
DOCKER_OPTS = DOCKER_OPTS="--cluster-store=consul://192.168.56.101:8500 --cluster-advertise=<VM-IP>:0 -H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376 -H unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
```

Comment: What kind of network do you create? A new VitualBox virtual network or a docker network?

Comment: A new docker network via "docker -H 0.0.0.0:3376 network create --subnet=172.11.0.0/16 testnetwork" which I connected to all nodes. If I ssh into those nodes I can then ping only the nodes running on the same virtual machine

Comment: try to supply the overlay driver instead of the default bridge. Then it should work

Comment: Still get the same error. The network is properly created I think, on each node with "docker network ls" I can see the network with overlay as driver

Comment: Before creating the docker network you can ping from on host to another and after creation not? Thats strange, because docker network should only affect containers and not the host.

Comment: No it does not affect the communication between the virtual machines. If I have one container running on each virtual machine and connect these containers via an overlay network, then SSH into one container and try to ping the other container, that ping fails

Comment: try omnitting the subnet option and ensure that the network id on both hosts is the same. If they are, I dont have a clue

Comment: Neither of those is the issue, docker -H... shows the same IPs as the docker inspect executed on both machines combined, so they have the exact same IP...removing the subnet slso does not work

Comment: Sorry I am afraid  I cannot help you.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have a direct quote, but from what I've read on Docker GitHub issue tracker, ICMP packets (ping) are never routed between containers on different nodes.

TCP connection to explicitly opened ports should work. But as of Docker 1.12.1 it is buggy.

Docker 1.12.2 has some bug fixes wrt establishing a connection to containers on other hosts. But ping is not going to work across hosts.

Answer (score 2):

You can only ping containers on the same node because you attach them to a *local scope* network.

As suggested in the comments, if you want to ping containers across hosts (meaning from a container on **VM1** to a container on **VM2**) using *docker swarm* (or *docker swarm mode*) *without explicitly opening ports*, you need to create an **overlay network** (or *globally scoped* network) and assign/start containers on that network.

To create an overlay network:

```
docker network create -d overlay mynet
```

Then start the containers using that network:

- For Docker Swarm mode:

  ```
    docker service create --replicas 2 --network mynet --name web nginx
  ```
- For Docker Swarm (legacy):

  ```
    docker run -itd --network=mynet busybox
  ```

For example, if we create two containers (on legacy Swarm):

```
docker run -itd --network=mynet --name=test1 busybox
docker run -itd --network=mynet --name=test2 busybox
```

You should be able to `docker attach` on `test2` to ping `test1` and vice-versa.

For more details you can refer to the [networking documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/).

> **Note**: If containers still can't ping each other after the creation of an overlay network and attaching containers to it, check the firewall configurations of the VMs and make sure that these ports are open:
>
> - data plane / **vxlan**: `UDP 4789`
> - control plane / **gossip**: `TCP/UDP 7946`